# Delete Pandas dataframe row, where the sum of all columns equals to 0

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way I can drop all rows in a pandas dataframe, where the sum of all columns is equal to 0?

Answer (score 3):

You can change logic - select all column with sum not equal `0` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.sum(axis=1).ne(0)]
```